# Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED] after changing package name

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have changed my project package name and i'm sure that all lettes are small letters and i don't have comments in the manifest but i got

```
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.worklight.androidnativepush.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.android.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.HARDWARE_TEST"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
    android:required="false" />

<application
    android:name=".RTA"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <service
        android:name=".Services.OrientationService"
        android:exported="false" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyADq1Ml1XMFdlmUHgvTtn-cT5rI3gVHC4M" />

    <activity android:name="com.worklight.wlclient.ui.UIActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Dashboard"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dashboard"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Dashboard1"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dashboard1"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         />
    <activity
        android:name=".Language"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_language"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Kit_corner"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kit_corner"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Kit_detailes"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kit_detailes"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Madinati.Madinati"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_madinati"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"

        android:screenOrientation="reverseLandscape" >

        </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Parking.click_add"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_click_add"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".TestAdaptersActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_test_adapters" />
    <activity
        android:name=".public_transport.view_nol_balance"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_view_nol_balance"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />
    <activity android:name=".pop_up.PopUp"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Base_activity"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_base_activity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".public_transport.view_my_balance"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_view_my_balance"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

    </activity>



    <activity
        android:name=".salik.Top_up_salik"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_top_up_salik"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".salik.accept"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_accept"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent4" >

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".salik.choose_user"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_choose_user"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent4" >

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".public_transport.Fare_calculator"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_fare_calculator"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".public_transport.get_marker"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_get_marker"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".public_transport.get_fare"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_get_fare"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent4" >

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Rotate_me"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_rotate_me"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent4" />
    <activity
        android:name=".About_RTA.Walkthrough"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".YouTubeWebView"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_you_tube_web_view"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <service
        android:name=".Utils.GPSTracker"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        tools:ignore="ExportedService,InnerclassSeparator" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Parking.select_zone"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_select_zone"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Settings.Login"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent4" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Settings.Register"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Parking.Add_plate"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add_plate"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Settings.Myvehicles"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_myvehicles"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Settings.Mynol"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_mynol"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Settings.mysalik"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_mysalik"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="Settings.Mydrivinglicense"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_mydrivinglicense"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Settings.Notifications"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_notifications"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Vehicles.View_fines_pay"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_view_fines_pay"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Vehicles.guest_view_fines_pay"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_guest_view_fines_pay"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Parking.Top_up_parking_account"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_top_up_parking_account"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".public_transport.nol_history"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_nol_history"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Vehicles_fines.mStore"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_m_store"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Vehicles_fines.Platenumber"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_platenumber"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Vehicles.View_fines_pay_registered"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_view_fines_pay_registered"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Vehicles.Renew_registration"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_renew_registration" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Driver.Renew_license"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_renew_license"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".About_RTA.RTA_services"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_rta_services"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".About_RTA.RTA_Info"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_rta__info"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".About_RTA.Contact_RTA"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_contact__rt"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".public_transport.TopUpNol"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_top_up_nol"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Vehicles.GreenPoint.green_point_calc"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_green_point_calc"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SaveFiles"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_save_files"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Vehicles.GreenPoint.green_calc_information"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_green_calc_information"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Vehicles.GreenPoint.green_points_view"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_green_points_view"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Parking.RememberMyLocation"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_remember_my_location"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Driver.FAQ"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_faq"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Vehicles.Test_center.view_test_center"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_view_test_center"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".salik.topUp_location.SalikLocation_center"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_view_test_center"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Driver.EyeTest"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_eye_test"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".About_RTA.Techniqal"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_techniqal"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Vehicles.Test_center.Vehicle_test_center"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_eye_test"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".About_RTA.Feedback"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_feedback" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Parking.top_up_parking.nnnnn"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_nnnnn" />
    <activity
        android:name=".About_RTA.All_RTA_Apps"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ParkingZoneAndTiming"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".PayParkingFeesActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".FAQNolActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />


    <activity
        android:name=".Vehicles_fines.FAQ_Vehicles"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".FAQDriversAndLicenseActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".FAQSalikActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SalikTopUpLocationActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".RTA_termAndConditions"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".HowToPayFinesDriversAndLicensingActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".HowToPayFinesActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".HowToPayParkingFinesActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MetroTimeTableActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_metro_time_table"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DubaiBusGuidesActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dubai_bus_guides"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ComingSoon"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/Comming_soon"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent4" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ErrorConnectionPopUP"
        android:label="@string/Comming_soon"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent4" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Vehicles.TrafficFileNumberInfo"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_traffic_file_number_info"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LostAndFoundActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_lost_and_found"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".WayToTopUpYouSalik"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_way_to_top_up_you_salik"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LicenseType"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_license_type"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="Point_of_Interest.Point_of_interest"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_point_of_interest"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".NotExpired"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_not_expired"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent4" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Vehicles.Retry_again"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_retry_again"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent4" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DubaiTramGuidesActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dubai_tram_guides" />
    <activity
        android:name=".PTLostAndFoundActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ptlost_and_found" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Vehicles.CollectionMap"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".kit_hello_activity"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kit_hello_activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"

        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent4"></activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".dashboard_hello_activity"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_title_dashboard_hello_activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent4"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Madinati.Madinati_Map"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_madinati__map"
        android:screenOrientation="reverseLandscape" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Madinati.Submit_Done"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_submit__done"
        android:screenOrientation="reverseLandscape"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent4" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ALHares.Hares_Submit_Done"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_hares__submit__done"
        android:screenOrientation="reverseLandscape" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Parking.ClickAndParkPopUp"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_click_and_park_pop_up"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent4" />
    <activity
        android:name=".About_RTA.RTAPrivacyPolicies"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_rtaprivacy_policies" >
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".Recievers.SmsListener">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity android:name=".Vehicles_fines.License_type" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

any help ?

Comment: You need to make sure the package name is changed everywhere. Do a ctrl-shift-f search for your original package name (cmd-shift-f in OS X)

Comment: i did but there is nothing

Comment: any other suggestion?

Comment: You can try a project clean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that some of your activities are not prefixed with a `.`